# Is there a way to export Microsoft Messenger custom emoticons?

Tags: windows-live-messenger, emoticons

Is there a way to export (or grab from disk) all the custom emotions set up on a Microsoft Messenger profile? Or better yet, is there a way of sharing them between multiple computers so that wherever I log on to Messenger I have the same custom emoticons configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this program - [MSN Backup](http://www.baisoft.it/msnbackup_english.asp). It is free and can do what you want!

Comment: Slightly quirky interface, and a little unsettling to enter my unique passport ID, but ? explains why (that ID is used as a key for the encryption). Export has worked. I assume restore will, but will return here if it doesn't.

Comment: ok... be careful, I had no idea that it required user info, I just went to a trusted forum and saw other people recommend this / said it worked... Did it ask for your password as well or just the user name?

Answer (score 0):

There's an app called [ConCon](http://www.topshareware.com/ConCon-Retriever-download-49518.htm) which is designed to export all your emoticons, I've used it successfully, its pretty simple but effective. The emoticons are exported as gifs.